# How to extract db version from oratab

Tags: text-processing, oracle

I have a requirement to extract the database version in order to fulfill a script requirement.

I need to fetch the db details from `oratab` and its version.

Suppose my entry in oratab as below :

```
dbname1:/oracle/app/oracle/11.2.0.4/db_1:Y
dbname2:/oracle/app/oracle/9.2.0.3/db_1:Y
```

Here I need to extract only the db versions like 11 or 9 for a particular database. Which means that the shell script should only display 11 or 9.

Comment: Does the answer below solve your problem? If not, please clarify; if so, please use the checkmark to indicate that to the system. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your version of `awk` supports regular expressions as the field separator, you can do this:

```
$ awk -F'[/.]' '{print $5}' oratab
11
9
```

alternatively, if you want the dbname printed too:

```
$ awk -F'[:/.]' '{print $1,$6}' oratab 
dbname1 11
dbname2 9
```

I'm not sure if the Solaris or AIX versions of `awk` supports regexps as field separator.  GNU `awk` does.  So does FreeBSD's version.  `mawk` and `original-awk` do too.

This should work on Solaris `awk` (should work on any `awk`):

```
awk -F'/' '/^#/ {next}; /kmad/ {sub(/\..*/,"",$5);print $5}' /etc/oratab
```

It skips lines beginning with a `#` comment, and then (for all lines containing `kmad`) it strips everything from the first `.` onwards from field 5, and then prints that field.

And if you've got some really weird `awk` that doesn't understand either regexps in the field-separator or the `next` statement, try this:

```
awk -F'/' '! /^#/ && /kmad/ {sub(/\..*/,"",$5);print $5}' /etc/oratab
```

and if your `awk` doesn't have `sub()` either, then it's not `awk`, it's a [dodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodo).  Bury it and get a real `awk`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40324/discussion-on-answer-by-cas-how-to-extract-db-version-from-oratab).